# Android passing information to a SingleInstance Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, single-instance, bundles

I have a activity that displays a number of elements from a list that the user can scroll through. In addition from navigating the list for new elements added the user can click a popup notification to immediately goto that element. I only ever want one instance of the list running so I made it a SingleInstance. Unfortunately that means if a user clicks the notification it ignores the startActivity() instead of jumping to that element.

My question is, is there a way I can make the notification either start the activity (bundled with which item to view) if it isn't up and if it is, receive the bundle and act on it?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an activity to only have one instance of it running, mark it with `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest.  This will cause Android to create the activity (if it doesn't exist) and call `onNewIntent(Intent)` on the activity.  From the caller's perspective, you simply fire off the intent as normal.

Comment: This solves my problem exactly! So much simpler than trying to set up a broadcastreciever to intercept my intent!